# How to enable scrolling on keydown?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found the code that prevents user to scrolling using keys for example pgup, pgdown, tab, space etc. when my gallery is loaded, but after closing the gallery I need to enable these keys. Can you help me with that?

Thank you

This is my code:

```
function disableK() {

var ar = new Array(9, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40);

$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if ($.inArray(key, ar) > -1) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
}
```

Comment: Just add a test for whether Gallery is open to your if.

Comment: so unbind the event!

Comment: But I don't know how... I am not that good in javascript yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also write a `enableK()` function that will use `.off()` to remove the event handler: http://api.jquery.com/off/

```
$(document).off("keydown");
```

This will remove all handlers attached to `document`. A better method would be to have a `boolean` flag that keeps track of whether or not your gallery is open, eg:

```
var isGalleryOpen = false;
```

When you open the gallery: `isGalleryOpen = true` and `= false` when you close it.

Then you can just write:

```
if ($.inArray(key, ar) > -1 && isGalleryOpen)
```

and it will only block key presses if the gallery is open.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store a named reference to the function that disables the keys. Then you can use that named function to remove the listener:

```
function disableKeys(e) {
    var ar = new Array(9, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40);
    var key = e.which;
    if ($.inArray(key, ar) > -1) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function disableK() {
    $(document).on('keydown', disableKeys);
}

function enableK() {
    $(document).off('keydown', disableKeys);
}
```